# Linked List implementation in python 3.x

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, linked-list

I took this as a challenge and implemented linked list data structure in python

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, nxt=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = nxt

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, arr=None):
        if arr in [None, []]:
            self.head = None
        else:
            self.arrayToLinked(arr)

    def arrayToLinked(self, arr):
        self.head = Node(arr[0])
        temp = self.head

        for i in range(1, len(arr)):
            temp.next = Node(arr[i])
            temp = temp.next

    def append(self, new_val):
        new_node = Node(new_val)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return

        last = self.head

        while last.next is not None:
            last = last.next
        last.next = new_node

    def linkedToArray(self):
        arr = []

        temp = self.head

        while temp is not None:
            arr.append(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next

        return arr

    def removeDuplicates(self):
        pass

    def sort(self):
        arr = []

        temp = self.head

        while temp is not None:
            arr.append(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next

        self.arrayToLinked(sorted(arr))

    def index(self, val):
        temp = self.head
        i = 0

        while temp is not None:
            if temp.data == val: return i
            i += 1
        return -1

    def min(self):
        mini = self.head.data
        temp = self.head

        while temp is not None:
            if mini > temp.data:
                mini = temp.data
        return mini

    def max(self):
        maxi = self.head.data
        temp = self.head

        while temp is not None:
            if maxi < temp.data:
                maxi = temp.data
        return maxi

    def push(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    @staticmethod
    def insertNode(prev_node, new_val):
        new_node = Node(new_val)
        new_node.next = prev_node.next
        prev_node.next = new_node

    def insertIndex(self, pos, data):
        data = Node(data)
        i = 0

        temp = self.head

        while i < pos:
            if temp is None or temp.next is None:
                return
            temp = temp.next
            i += 1

        dum = temp
        temp = data
        temp.next = dum
        self.head = temp

    def delete(self, key):
        temp = self.head

        if temp is not None and temp.data == key:
            self.head = temp.next
            return

        prev = None

        while temp is not None:
            if temp.data == key:
                break
            prev = temp
            temp = temp.next

        if temp is None:
            return

        prev.next = temp.next

    def deleteIndex(self, pos):
        if self.head is None:
            return

        temp = self.head

        if pos == 0:
            self.head = temp.next
            return

        for i in range(pos - 1):
            temp = temp.next

            if temp is None:
                break

        if temp is None or temp.next is None:
            return

        val = temp.next.next
        temp.next = None
        temp.next = val

    def pop(self, pos):
        if self.head is None:
            return

        temp = self.head

        if pos == 0:
            self.head = temp.next
            return

        for i in range(pos - 1):
            temp = temp.next

            if temp is None:
                break

        if temp is None or temp.next is None:
            return

        val = temp.next.next
        pop_val = temp.next
        temp.next = None
        temp.next = val

        return pop_val

    def count(self, element):
        temp = self.head
        count = 0

        while temp is not None:
            if temp.data == element:
                count += 1
            temp = temp.next
        return count

    def remove(self, element):
        temp = self.head

        while temp is not None:
            if temp.next is not None and temp.next.data == element:
                dum = temp.next.next
                temp.next = None
                temp.next = dum
            temp = temp.next

    def isLoop(self):
        s = set()
        temp = self.head

        while temp:
            if temp in s:
                return True
            s.add(temp)
            temp = temp.next
        return False

    def findLoop(self):
        s = set()
        temp = self.head

        while temp:
            if temp in s:
                return temp
            s.add(temp)
            temp = temp.next

    def createLoop(self, data):
        ind = self.index(data)

        last = self.head

        while last.next is not None:
            last = last.next

        last.next = self[ind]

    def reverse(self):
        result = None

        temp = self.head

        while temp:
            result = Node(temp.data, temp)
            temp = temp.next

        self.head = result

    def len(self):
        c = 0
        temp = self.head

        while temp is not None:
            c += 1
            temp = temp.next

        return c

    def clear(self):
        self.head = None

    def copy(self):
        return self.arrayToLinked(self.linkedToArray())

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        arr = []
        temp = self.head

        while temp is not None:
            arr.append(temp)
            temp = temp.next

        return arr[index]

    def getValues(self, index):
        arr = []
        temp = self.head

        while temp is not None:
            arr.append(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next

        return arr[index]

    def print(self):
        arr = []
        m = self.head

        while m is not None:
            arr.append(str(m.data))
            m = m.next

        print(' -> '.join(arr))
```

I want to make the code as short as possible, while maintaining neatness.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is pretty neat. One major improvement would be the addition of some *magic* methods, like `__iter__`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` and `__str__`.

## **iter**

The magic method you'll use the most wil be `__iter__`. It will allow you to do `for node in linked_list`

```
def __iter__(self):
    current = self.head
    while current:
        yield current
        current = current.next
```

If there is the possibility for loops in the linked list, this will go on forever. In that case, it might be best to raise a specific exception

```
class LoopListError(Exception): pass
...
def __iter__(self):
    current = self.head
    visited = set()
    while current:
        if current in visited:
            raise LoopListError("f{current} is part of a loop")
        set.add(current)
        yield current
        current = current.next
```

Make sure never to change the list while iterating over it. This might lead to strange errors.

## `__len__`

len(self) can be renamed to `__len_`, so you can do `len(linked_list)` . It can also be implemented like this:

```
def __len__(self):
    return sum(1 for _ in self)
```

If there is a loop in the list, this wil raise the `LoopListError`. If, in that case,  you want the length of the non-looped part of the list, then you can do:

```
def __len__(self):
    count = 0
    try:
        for _ in self:
            count += 1
    except LoopListError:
        pass
    return count
```

If you want it to iterate over the nodes values instead of the nodes themselves, you can just change the `yield current` to `yield current.data`. Whichever option is best depends on the design of the rest and the use of this list.

I think it's cleaner to provide a separate `iter_values` method:

```
def iter_values(self):
    return (node.data for node in self)
```

You don't need a specific `min` and `max` method any more, but can use the builtins

## `__getitem__`

In your implementation, you load the complete linked list into a builtin `list`. This is not needed. You can use `enumerate` to loop over the elements, and keep track of the index

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    for i, node in enumerate(self):
        if i == index:
            return node
    raise IndexError(f"{index} not found")
```

This works for positive indices. If you also want to accept negative indices, you need to convert the negative index to a positive one:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    if index < 0:
        l = len(self)
        if abs(index) > l:
            raise IndexError(f"{index} out of range")
        index = l - index

    for i, node in enumerate(self):
        if i == index:
            return node
    raise IndexError(f"{index} out of range")
```

## `__bool__`

In python, by convention, empty containers are *falsey*. Their `__bool__` function returns `False`.

```
def __bool__(self):
    return self.head is not None
```

## `arrayToLinked`

In python, it's seldomly necessary to loop over an index. Instead of `for i in range(1, len(arr))`, you can use `for value in arr:`. This only needs a bit of special handling for the head of the list.

Your `arrayToLinked` method corresponds to `list.extend(iterable)`  on an ordinary list. I only clears the list first. My suggestion would be to skip the clearing of the list. If the user wants a fresh list, he can either explicitly clear it himself, or call the constructor while providing the iterable:

```
def extend(self, iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if not self:
        try:
            self.head = Node(next(it))
        except StopIteration:
            self.head = None

    for value in it:
        self.append(Node(value))

def __init__(self, iterable=None):
    self.head = None
    if iterable is not None:
        self.extend(iterable)
```

---

As409_conflict noted in the comments, this might not be the most performant method to use

if you provide a `tail` method,

```
def tail(self):
    """
    returns the last element in the linked list. 
    """

    if self.head is None:
        return None
    for current in self:
        pass
    return current


def extend(self, iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if not self:
        try:
            self.head = Node(next(it))
        except StopIteration:
            return
    current = self.tail()

    for value in it:
        current.next = current = Node(value)
```

## `copy`

The copy then becomes as simple as

```
def copy(self):
    return type(self)(self.iter_values())
```

## `sort`

```
def sort(self):
    sorted_values = sorted(self.iter_values())
    self.clear()
    self.extend(sorted_values )
```

Or, If you want to return a new instance

```
def sort(self):
    return type(self)(sorted(self.iter_values()))
```

---

In general, I suggest you take a look at the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), and what methods a standard `list` provides, and thy to mimic those behaviours

Comment: Due to the linear complexity of append, your extend complexity is squared. Better incorporate the looping there or introduce `self._last`.